# angular brackets (textlangle) in table with siunitx

Tags: tables, siunitx, threeparttable, textcomp

I want to use angular brackets as produced by \textlangle and \textrangle from the textcomp package in a table. I am using siunitx to handle digits, alignment, and so on, but I get an unnecessary space after the \textlangle. I think this is because I am not specifying it as an input symbol but when I try to I get errors. A MWE is here (I am using XeLaTeX, but would be happy not to):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=0.9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{siunitx}
  \sisetup{
    detect-all,
    group-digits      = false,
    input-symbols     = ( ) [ ] - + ,
    table-align-text-post = false,
    input-signs             = ,
        } 

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}




\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{table}\centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
  \vspace{.75ex}
   \begin{tabular}{>{\hspace{0pt}}p{2.5cm}*{7}{S[table-format=1.3,table-column-width=15mm]}}
   \toprule
                   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)}         \\
                  \midrule 

$\alpha$         &    0.044         &                  &     0.27\sym{***}&     0.28\sym{***}&                  &                  &                  \\
                &   (0.11)         &                  &  (0.082)         &  (0.082)         &                  &                  &                  \\
                &\textlangle{}0.68\textrangle{}         &                  &\textlangle{}0.0021\textrangle{}         &\textlangle{}0.0016\textrangle{}         &                  &                  & \\
                &    0.070         &                  &     0.50         &     0.51         &                  &                  &                  \\
                &{[}{-0.26 {,}0.41}{]}         &                  &{[}{0.20 {,}0.79}{]}         &{[}{0.22 {,}0.80}{]}         &                  &                  &                  \\

$\beta$         &    0.044         &                  &     0.27\sym{***}&     0.28\sym{***}&                  &                  &                  \\
                &   (0.11)         &                  &  (0.082)         &  (0.082)         &                  &                  &                  \\
                &\textlangle{}0.68\textrangle{}         &                  &\textlangle{}0.0021\textrangle{}         &\textlangle{}0.0016\textrangle{}         &                  &                  & \\
                &    0.070         &                  &     0.50         &     0.51         &                  &                  &                  \\
                &{[}{-0.26 {,}0.41}{]}         &                  &{[}{0.20 {,}0.79}{]}         &{[}{0.22 {,}0.80}{]}         &                  &                  &                  \\

$\gamma$         &    0.044         &                  &     0.27\sym{***}&     0.28\sym{***}&                  &                  &                  \\
                &   (0.11)         &                  &  (0.082)         &  (0.082)         &                  &                  &                  \\
                &\textlangle{}0.68\textrangle{}         &                  &\textlangle{}0.0021\textrangle{}         &\textlangle{}0.0016\textrangle{}         &                  &                  & \\
                &    0.070         &                  &     0.50         &     0.51         &                  &                  &                  \\
                &{[}{-0.26 {,}0.41}{]}         &                  &{[}{0.20 {,}0.79}{]}         &{[}{0.22 {,}0.80}{]}         &                  &                  &                  \\
                \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \end{threeparttable}
  \end{table}
  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=0.9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newrobustcmd{\lan}{\textlangle}
\newrobustcmd{\ran}{\textrangle}

\sisetup{
  detect-all,
  group-digits = false,
  input-symbols = ( ) [ ] - + \lan \ran,
  table-align-text-post = false,
} 

\newcommand{\sym}[1]{\ensuremath{^{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
 w{l}{15mm}
 *{7}{S[table-column-width=18mm]}
}
\toprule
& {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)} & {(4)} & {(5)} & {(6)} & {(7)} \\
\midrule 

$\alpha$
&    0.044          &                  &    0.27\sym{***} &    0.28\sym{***} &                  &                  &                  \\
&   (0.11)          &                  &  (0.082)         &  (0.082)         &                  &                  &                  \\
&\lan 0.68\ran      &                  &\lan 0.0021\ran   &\lan 0.0016\ran   &                  &                  & \\
&    0.070          &                  &     0.50         &     0.51         &                  &                  &                  \\
&{$[-0.26{,}0.41]$} &                  &{$[0.20{,}0.79]$} &{$[0.22{,}0.80]$} &                  &                  &                  \\

$\beta$
&    0.044          &                  &     0.27\sym{***}&    0.28\sym{***} &                  &                  &                  \\
&   (0.11)          &                  &  (0.082)         &  (0.082)         &                  &                  &                  \\
&\lan 0.68\ran      &                  &\lan 0.0021\ran   &\lan 0.0016\ran   &                  &                  & \\
&    0.070          &                  &     0.50         &     0.51         &                  &                  &                  \\
&{$[-0.26{,}0.41]$} &                  &{$[0.20{,}0.79]$} &{$[0.22{,}0.80]$} &                  &                  &                  \\

$\gamma$
&    0.044          &                  &    0.27\sym{***} &     0.28\sym{***}&                  &                  &                  \\
&   (0.11)          &                  &  (0.082)         &  (0.082)         &                  &                  &                  \\
&\lan 0.68\ran      &                  &\lan 0.0021\ran   &\lan 0.0016\ran   &                  &                  & \\
&    0.070          &                  &     0.50         &     0.51         &                  &                  &                  \\
&{$[-0.26{,}0.41]$} &                  &{$[0.20{,}0.79]$} &{$[0.22{,}0.80]$} &                  &                  &                  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the simpler (and better) `{$[-0.26{,}0.41]$}` for the intervals in every fifth line. Also `\sym` is defined in the right way.

Comment: This works perfectly (with pdflatex). Thank you. Also grateful for the improvements to \sym and the intervals. I'm going to accept this answer.